# Remove unwanted characters from string by regex in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have a string here:

```
javax.swing.JLabel[,380,30,150x25,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0]: Hello
```

I want to remove everything before the ":", including the ":" itself. This would leave only `"Hello"`. I read about regex, but no combination I tried worked. Can someone tell me how to do it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `replaceAll` method or `replaceFirst`.

```
string.replaceFirst(".*:\\s*", "");
```

or

```
string.replaceAll(".*:\\s*", "");
```

This would give you only `Hello`. If you remove `\\s*` pattern,then it would give you `<space>Hello` string.

- `.*` Matches any character zero or more times, greedily.
- `:` Upto the colon.
- `\\s*` Matches zero or more space characters.

Answer (score 1):

You could also just split the string by `:` and take the second string. Like this

```
String sample = "javax.swing.JLabel[,380,30,150x25,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0]: Hello";

System.out.println(sample.split(":", -1)[1]);
```

This will output

```
<space>Hello
```

If you want to get rid of that leading space just `trim` it off like

```
System.out.println(sample.split(":", -1)[1].trim());
```